# Gmaps4rails: How to add a custom marker to json in server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, gmaps4rails

Is it possible to add a custom marker to json after this:

```
@json = @myObjects.to_gmaps4rails
```

I'd like to add one more marker to that json, which would be other than myObject. Actually in my case it would be marker that would represent user location. I have all the needed information in my controller, but what is the easiest way to extend that json with one more marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions here:

- some string manipulations
- Parse the json => Array of hashes => add your data to the array => call to_json on the array